# Keyboard shortcut to CLI executable

Tags: keyboard, script, mapping

[image]I have a couple CLI utilities I would like to map to key combinations. The scripts take no parameters, I merely need to invoke them.

I've seen [how to create keyboard shortcuts to apps](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2013/11/11/how-to-create-keyboard-shortcuts-specific-commands-in-your-favorite-apps/), but can I point them to an executable somehow?

Comment: What exactly have you seen for creating keyboard shortcuts for apps as the same process could be adapted for executables?

Comment: I just put a link in my question. The other examples I've seen are all the same. How to link keys to an application, but I haven't seen a place to enter a command instead.

Comment: The link you've added refers to adding keyboard shortcuts to existing menu items in apps that are open. Do you want to have keyboard shortcuts perform key presses in Terminal CLIs, or run the CLIs themselves?

Comment: Run the CLIs themselves. Ideally I just want to define a key combo, then enter an absolute path to a command to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you would want to use Automator. You do not need to know about AppleScript to use Automator (in fact, if you open up Automator, you will quickly find that it really is self-evident).

The trick is not just to tie your CLI service to an Automator app, but to be able to get to that globally using a Keyboard shortcut. That can be achieved using a Service. [This tutorial explains quite well](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-launch-any-app-with-a-keyboard-shortcut--mac-31463) how to do what you are looking for... in fact, describing a very similar scenario.

I take no credit for the tutorial content, only found it to solve a similar problem (I needed to map some drives at Startup without Finder.app opening while doing so).

Comment: This doesn't look like it will work. I navigated to the executable on my disk and it's greyed out. This is a BASH script I'm trying to launch, not an application.

Comment: Assuming you have a `script.sh` of some sort, open up Automator. Choose Service Receives: 'no input' in 'any application' Under Actions, choose Utilities. Drag 'Run Shell Script' to your workflow. Enter the path to the script file there. Test it right in the Automator interface.

Comment: I've found the 'Run Shell Script' now, but don't see the new service in Settings when trying to add the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Did you set Service Receives 'No Input' in 'Any Application'?

Comment: Yes, take a peak at the screenshot I just uploaded.

Comment: And when you saved it, you should see that, in any application, you can click on the Application Name, Choose Services, and see the name of your service there. If you do, then you should be able to see it in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts tab -> Services. It will likely be near the bottom... under General. The workflow itself is stored in ~/Library/Services/

Comment: Maybe I saved it wrong somehow? lol

Comment: Let me know if you got it to work. It worked without issue on my MacBook Pro.

Comment: I think I've given up for now. I'll try on another Mac when I get home for sanity's sake.

Comment: Seems I needed to run a [`/System/Library/CoreServices/pbs`](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20012936-263.html). Got it working, thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with [**Keyboard Maestro**](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/), using a macro such as this:

[image: Upon hotkey ⌥⇧⌘S, execute AppleScript tell application "Terminal" activate set currentTab to do script ("echo hi") end tell]

Comment: Thanks for this. I like the more native approach from the answer I accepted, but I never specified a preference in my question. +1